# In Excel, what is the appropriate function to use to find an item in a column that corresponds to an item in a column beside it?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Imagine that I have an Excel column

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
```

Then I have the following table

```
option1 | ABC, DEF
option2 | GHI, JKL, MNO
option3 | PQR, STU .... (could be hundreds of comma separated values long in the same field)
```

Now I want to find which option in the array each item in the first column corresponds to.

For example, I would like as a final product to have:

```
ABC | option1
DEF | option1
GHI | option2
JKL | option2
MNO | option2
```

I have tried VLOOKUP, but am not getting the desired results. I have also tried separating each comma separated value as separate columns.

Any ideas on the best function for me to use for this?

Comment: Just passing by, without time to thoroughly test, but I've had much better luck with LOOKUP(MATCH()) style lookups than VLOOKUP; might give it a look - some details here http://thinketg.com/say-goodbye-to-vlookup-and-hello-to-index-match/

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are willing to help, but need more info. Please share the `VLOOKUP` you have attempted so we can help you with it. What results is it giving compared to what you desire? Also, what research have you done on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

With the list in column **A** and the *Option* table in columns **D & E**, in cell **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH("*" & A1 & "*",E$1:E$3,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

This is possible because *MATCH()* supports wild cards.

As **Engineer Toast** points out:

- Match will return the first match found
- Match will return **#N/A** if no match is found
- Match is **not** case sensitive
- Match supports wild cards

Comment: +1 confirmed operational. Returns `#N/A` if not found. Key point to OP: This finds the first instance. If `ABC` shows up for multiple options, this function returns the first one in the list.

Answer (score 0):

So the problems you are likely having are

1. Vlookup can only search left to right (it can't return a column to the left of your lookup column
2. Vlookup needs an exact match so you need to concatenate wildcard characters on either side (*)

So you have two options use the data as you have it (options in column A, data in column B) and use an index match function

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH("*" & D2 & "*",$B$2:$B$4,0))
```

or reverse the data and use vlookup or index match would still work

```
=VLOOKUP("*" & D2 & "*",$A$6:$B$8,2,FALSE)
```

[image]